# Can someone please explain the working of for loop in this snippet

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
permutationWithRepeation("PQR");

 }

private static void permutationWithRepeation(String str1) {
System.out.println("The given string is: PQR");
System.out.println("The permuted strings are:");
showPermutation(str1, "");
 }
private static void showPermutation(String str1, String NewStringToPrint) {

if (NewStringToPrint.length() == str1.length()) {
   System.out.println(NewStringToPrint);
   return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {

   showPermutation(str1, NewStringToPrint + str1.charAt(i));
  }
 }
}
```

I am not able to understand after PPP
The output of the code is
The given string is: PQR
The permuted strings are:
PPP
PPQ
PPR
PQP
PQQ
PQR
PRP
PRQ
PRR
QPP
QPQ
QPR
QQP
QQQ
QQR
QRP
QRQ
QRR
RPP
RPQ
RPR
RQP
RQQ
RQR
RRP
RRQ
RRR

Comment: You may want to set a breakpoint on the println statement and look at the call stack.  You will see that there are several calls each having their own value of I.

Comment: Adding nonsense-text to your question to circumvent the automated quality check is not a good idea. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is recursion. On each recursion level you put character at next position. Loop at each level is used to put all possible characters at next position and to go into next recursion level. When all characters are set your string has length 3 and recursion stops.